# C_icap error linking with pthread

Tags: c, ubuntu, linker, pthreads, glibc

I am tying to install c_icap on Ubuntu 11 and getting the following errors.

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/madmin/milkyway/sol/server/3rdparty/c_icap-0.1.7/tests'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -I../include/ -D_REENTRANT -g -O2 -Wall -rdynamic -rpath /usr/local/c_icap/lib   -o test_cache test_cache.o  **-lpthread** ../libicapapi.la  -ldl
libtool: link: gcc -I../include/ -D_REENTRANT -g -O2 -Wall -rdynamic -o .libs/test_cache test_cache.o  **-lpthread** ../.libs/libicapapi.so -ldl -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/c_icap/lib
../.libs/libicapapi.so: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
../.libs/libicapapi.so: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
../.libs/libicapapi.so: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Not sure what the problem is, since i saw the objdump of the **libicap.so** and got this

```
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000              pthread_rwlock_rdlock
0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000000    pthread_mutex_destroy@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000              pthread_rwlock_wrlock
0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000000   pthread_mutex_unlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000              pthread_rwlock_unlock
```

Which shows that pthread lib is not missing as pthread_mutex symbols are correctly resolved in the objdump. Also -lpthread flag is also present.

In the Makefile i have

```
THREADS_LDADD = -lpthread
c_icap_LDADD = -lpthread libicapapi.la  -ldl
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Compile with `-pthread` instead.

This will include all that is needed.